# How to transform global coordinates to local coordinates?

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems, rotations, transformation, geometric-transformation

For example, I have 4 points with the following global coordinates $(4,2),(5,3),(6,4),(8,5)$.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5vKl.png)

How to transform these global coordinates into local, such that the first point is $(0,0)$ in the new local coordinate system, and that x axis goes through the second point.
[Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6owV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You know you want to make a rotation to the axes and then a translation :
$$\begin{pmatrix}
X\\
Y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b\\
b & a 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
c\\
d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here you have $c=4$ and $d=2$. In order to find $a$ and $b$, you take the normed director vector $u$ from the line which pass through $(4,2)$ and $(5,3)$ and the director vector $v=(1,0)$, and you solve for $a$ and $b$ :
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b\\
b & a 
\end{pmatrix}u$$